# "if not item in list" not functioning properly in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple program that checks the user's 'passcode' that either allows them access or denies them access.

If the user types in the correct passcode, the print statement "Login successful! Passcode used:", passcode" is printed, however, if the passcode is wrong, it simply asks for their passcode again **without** printing the statement "Login unsuccessful."...

Why is this? Thankyou.

```
LoginCorrect = 0
lst = ['1234', '2345', '3456', '4567', '5678', '6789']
while LoginCorrect == 0:
    passcode = input("Please enter your passcode: ")
    for item in lst:
        if item == passcode:
            print("Login successful! Passcode used:", passcode)
            LoginCorrect = 1
        if not item in lst == False:
            print("Login unsuccessful.")
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. In fact it's printing "Login unsuccessful" at least 5 times. Are you using python2 or python3?

Comment: Could be that you are using Python 2, in which case you should use `raw_input()` rather than `input()`.

Comment: @Rawing I am using Python 3

Comment: @cdarke I am using Python 3

Comment: Why would you even check `if not item in list` inside `for item in lst`?! There is only one possible outcome at that point. And why compare that to `False` rather than use `if item in lst:`?

Comment: `not item in lst == False` yields `item in lst == True`

Comment: @discipline: Not as such. Try this: `lst = [1, 2, 3]; a = [(i, not i in lst == False, i in lst == True) for i in range(5)]; print(a)`. Also see my answer.

Comment: Except that we are iterating through each item in lst. Obviously the item will be in the list so the condition always evaluates the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a `while` statement with `continue` and `break`?

```
lst = ['1234', '2345', '3456', '4567', '5678', '6789']

while True:
    passcode = input('Please enter your passcode: ')
    if passcode not in lst:
       continue
    else:
        print("Login successful! Passcode used:", passcode)
        break
```

You state "if the passcode is wrong, it simply asks for their passcode again without printing the statement "Login unsuccessful."
That being the case, why are you coding for "Login Unsuccessful" ?

Answer (score 4):

You're over complicating things. Instead of iterating over the list yourself, you could just check if the `passcode` is there:

```
LoginCorrect = False
lst = ['1234', '2345', '3456', '4567', '5678', '6789']
while LoginCorrect:
    passcode = input("Please enter your passcode: ")
    if passcode in lst:
        print("Login successful! Passcode used:", passcode)
        LoginCorrect = True
    else:
        print("Login unsuccessful.")
```

Comment: The code I have provided is a basic version of my actual program. In my actual program, each item in lst must be tested individually. I need the for loop to be part of the answer. Would you please be able to edit my original program, keeping the for loop in your solution.

Comment: @Cooper The 'in' operator will do exactly the same for you and is much more efficient in doing so and also makes the code more readable.

Comment: @Cooper: In that case you should add some info to the end of your question so that people answering know that your real code needs a `for` loop, and you should also explain _why_ you believe the `for` loop to be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question: `not item in lst` works fine, but 
`not item in lst == False` is evaluated differently than you probably expect.
Python converts chains of logical tests like `(a == b == c)` or `(a in b in c)`
to `(a == b) and (b == c)` or `(a in b) and (b in c)`. It also does this When it 
sees `in` and `==` in the same expression. So `not item in lst == False` is evaluated as
`not ((item in lst) and (lst == False))`, which is always `True`. (Without the `not`, it 
would always be `False`, which may be what prompted your original question).

You could fix this by putting parentheses around your first test: `(not item in lst) == False` (or maybe you mean `True`?). But a better way to write this test would be `if item not in lst:`.
There are also a couple of other problems with the organization of your code, which
I've pointed out in comments below:

```
LoginCorrect = 0   # probably better to use True/False here
lst = ['1234', '2345', '3456', '4567', '5678', '6789']
while LoginCorrect == 0:
    # The next line will not work right on Python 2.x, which has a different
    # input() function; if your code might run on 2.x you should adjust for that.
    passcode = input("Please enter your passcode: ")
    for item in lst:
        if item == passcode:
            print("Login successful! Passcode used:", passcode)
            LoginCorrect = 1
            # you could use a 'break' here to avoid comparing to more items

        # As noted above, `if item not in lst:` would work better for the next line.
        # This test should also probably occur after the `for` loop instead of 
        # inside it, and act based on `LoginCorrect` instead of `item`. As it is, 
        # you are testing whether `item` is in `lst`, which it always is, and you  
        # are doing this test once for each `item`, which is more checks than needed.

        if not item in lst == False:
            print("Login unsuccessful.")
```

You mentioned in a comment on a different answer that you have to use a `for` loop to 
test the passcode against each item. If that's true, then the revised code below
could work well:

```
try:
    # Python 2 compatibility
    input = raw_input
except NameError:
    pass

LoginCorrect = False
lst = ['1234', '2345', '3456', '4567', '5678', '6789']
while not LoginCorrect:
    passcode = input("Please enter your passcode: ")
    for item in lst:
        if item == passcode:
            print("Login successful! Passcode used:", passcode)
            LoginCorrect = True
            break
    if not LoginCorrect:
        print("Login unsuccessful.")
```

Or, if you are willing to drop the `for` loop, you can make your code much simpler:

```
try:
    # Python 2 compatibility
    input = raw_input
except NameError:
    pass

lst = ['1234', '2345', '3456', '4567', '5678', '6789']
while True:
    passcode = input("Please enter your passcode: ")
    if passcode in lst:
        print("Login successful! Passcode used:", passcode)
        break
    else:
        print("Login unsuccessful.")
```

Comment: @PM2Ring: on my computer and apparently on @Rawing's computer, the "Login unsuccessful" message is printed multiple times (not never). This is because on my system (Python 2.7), `not item in lst == False` always evaluates to True (counter to your example and the original poster's experience). This may be a difference between 2.7 and 3.

Comment: FWIW, Python 2 & Python 3 don't behave differently re these chained comparisons. I should know better than to shoot my mouth off before actually testing other people's code... :)

Comment: No worries, looks like we both ended up in the same place! Thanks for pointing out my misreading of the chained boolean expressions -- learned something new there!

Answer (score 1):

The logic of your code is somewhat unclear. I *think* you meant to do something like this:

```
LoginCorrect = 0
lst = ['1234', '2345', '3456', '4567', '5678', '6789']
while LoginCorrect == 0:
    passcode = input("Please enter your passcode: ")
    for item in lst:
        if item == passcode:
            print("Login successful! Passcode used:", passcode)
            LoginCorrect = 1
            break
    if passcode not in lst:
        print("Login unsuccessful.")
```

BTW, it would be more usual in Python to use the booleans `False` and `True` for your `LoginCorrect` flag, eg

```
lst = ['1234', '2345', '3456', '4567', '5678', '6789']
LoginCorrect = False
while not LoginCorrect:
    passcode = input("Please enter your passcode: ")
    for item in lst:
        if item == passcode:
            print("Login successful! Passcode used:", passcode)
            LoginCorrect = True
            break
    if passcode not in lst:
        print("Login unsuccessful.")
```

However, as others have said, it's inefficient to use a Python loop to test if `passcode` is in `lst`. An `in` test does that more efficiently, and it would be even more efficient if `lst` were instead a `set` of valid passcodes.

```
lst = {'1234', '2345', '3456', '4567', '5678', '6789'}
while True:
    passcode = input("Please enter your passcode: ")
    if passcode in lst:
        print("Login successful! Passcode used:", passcode)
        break
    print("Login unsuccessful.")
```

---

I have to mention that one of the `if` statements in your code does *not* do what you think it does:

```
if not item in lst == False:
```

To explain why, I need to take a slight detour. :)

Python syntax supports the chaining of relational operators. This allows you to do things like

```
if 0 <= a < 5:
```

or even

```
if 0 <= a < 5 <= b < 10:
```

The chained test `0 <= a < 5` is equivalent to `(0 <= a) and (a < 5)`,
and `0 <= a < 5 <= b < 10` is equivalent to

```
(0 <= a) and (a < 5) and (5 <= b) and (b < 10)
```

The `and` operator short-circuits, which means that in

```
left_expression and right_expression
```

it *only* evaluates `right_expression` if `bool(left_expression)` is True. So in those chained tests, Python works from left to right, breaking out of the chain if it detects a falsey result at any stage.

Also, in chained tests any of the intermediate expressions are guaranteed to be evaluated at most once. Eg, in `f() < g() < h()` the function `g` is called once at most, and it will only be called if `f()` returns a non-falsey result.

Now, to get back to your code. :)

The `in` operator is a relational operator, so it can be used in chained tests. So

```
if item in lst == True:
```

is equivalent to

```
if (item in lst) and (lst == True):
```

and

```
if not item in lst == False:
```

is equivalent to

```
if not ((item in lst) and (lst == False)):
```

I think you'll agree that's **not** what you meant to say! :)

And now you should be able to understand why this weird piece of code prints `True`

```
ab = ('a', 'b')
print('b' in ab in [('a', 'b'), 'c'])
```

Comment: On my computer, with Python 2.7, both `not 1 in [1, 2] == False` and `not 5 in [1, 2] == False` evaluate to `True`. But `(not (1 in [1, 2])) and ([1, 2] == False)` evaluates to `False`. This contradicts your explanation of how these expressions are parsed. Do you get the same results? If not, maybe there is some difference between how Python 2.7 and 3 parse these expressions? I can't find any way to break these expressions into smaller parts and still get the same answer; it's mystifying!

Comment: Actually, this has a simple explanation. `not 1 in [1, 2] == False` is parsed as `not ((1 in [1, 2]) and ([1, 2] == False))`.

Comment: @mfripp: Oops! Yes, I misremembered the relative precedence of `not`. I've fixed that part of my answer.

Comment: Yeah, it took me a while to figure out how `not` would be applied too. Eventually I tried  `not 1 == 2 == 3`, which made it clear.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this is just an excersise and not a production code to perform login, because it is **super not secured**.

Here is a working version of your snippet:

```
lst = ['1234', '2345', '3456', '4567', '5678', '6789']
LoginCorrect = False
while not LoginCorrect:
    passcode = input("Please enter your passcode: ")
    if passcode in lst:
        print("Login successful! Passcode used:", passcode)
        LoginCorrect = True
    else:
        print("Login unsuccessful.")
```